# Adding a counter for the correct answer to determine the users score

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add a counter that will determine the users score if the user inputs the correct answer. Though I can't seem to figure out how to add it into this if statement, or whether I need a new if statement.

This is the code to check the answer.

```
private void btnCheckAnswer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Answer = txtGuess.Text;

        if (Answer.ToLower().Equals(country[index].ToLower()))
            MessageBox.Show("Correct!");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!");
    }
```

How would you add a counter that will be equivalent to the answer the user inputs. This counter will be displayed in a label called lblScoreCount.

Thank you for time, Ben

Comment: You could make a new global `int` variable and increment it in the `if` statement when they get the answer right.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using *properties*, do not add `lblScoreCount` changing into `if` statement, but put it into property `set`.

```
private int m_Attempts = 0;
// You may want this as well
private int m_CorrectAnswers = 0;

private void ChangeScore() {
  lblScoreCount.Text = String.Format("{0} right answers from {1} attempts",
    CorrectAnswers, Attempts);
}

private int Attempts {
  get {
    return m_Attempts;
  }
  set {
    m_Attempts = value; 
    ChangeScore();
  }
}

// You may want this as well
private int CorrectAnswers {
  get {
    return m_CorrectAnswers;
  }
  set {
    m_CorrectAnswers = value; 
    ChangeScore();
  }
}
```

Properties can leave the main logic as simple as it's possible:

```
private void btnCheckAnswer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string Answer = txtGuess.Text;

  Attempts += 1;

  if (String.Equals(txtGuess.Text, 
                    country[index], 
                    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
    CorrectAnswers += 1;
    MessageBox.Show("Correct!");
  }
  else {
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!");
  }
}
```

Comment: @Benancio Morales: *every* attempt (either right or wrong) adds 1 for `Attempts`, but only *right* ones add for `CorrectAnswers`; So you can have a score like *3 right answers from 5 attempts*

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add curly braces to your if statement to allow multiple statements in the true case:

```
// counter somewhere in your module/class/form/...
int counter = 0;

// ...
if(Answer.ToLower() == country[index].ToLower()) {
    MessageBox.Show("Correct!");
    counter++;
} // ...
```

Comment: Tried your code out and it works, of course, thank you for the reply.